# working with activities having same app signature

Tags: android

I am beginner in android.  I have created one test application which consists of 9 activities for various purposes registered in manifest file as LAUNCHER ACTIVITY.  But, i am running only one activity at a time by using the Run configurations option.   if i disconnect the device from my PC after launching the application and relaunch it from the LAUNCHER application. Then, it is displaying the first activity which i have installed on this device with the same app signature.

Can anyone please help me to understand why the activity is not maintained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating different activities and assigning all of them as launcher activities is not the correct way. There should be only one Launcher activity through which the flow of your application will start. You can start other activities using the following code

```
startActivity(new Intent (ActivityA.this, ActivityB.java));
```

If you have 9 launcher activities then in your device you would have 9 different icons for different activities of the same application, which is not proper at all!

Answer (score 0):

I think its working as it should work.

All your activities can't be LAUNCHER activities in Manifest file. One activity can be LAUNCHER. All other activities can be started via intent.

E.g. First page (say, WelcomeScreen.java) will be launcher activity. Then on click of some button or on any other event, you will have to call

```
startActivity(new Intent (this, NextActivity.java))
```

And so on..
When you will start the app again, WelcomeScreen.java will be displayed again.